# Automatically create variables from environment parameters

Tags: php

I am working on a legacy PHP website as a favour for someone and I have set the site up locally but one thing that doesn't work is that the code seems to behave as though environment parameters (for example Gets, Posts, PHP_AUTH_USER etc) all seem to be magically turn into pre set variables and I can't see how.

The code looks like

`<? if ($division) { ?>` or `<? if ($PHP_AUTH_USER) { ?>`

but won't work locally till I change it to

`<? if ($_GET['division']) { ?>` or `<? if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) { ?>`

These lines of code are at the top of the page and there are no previous includes that could be doing it somewhere else.

Any ideas? Is this a setting in the PHP configuration that I have missed?

Comment: Best to change it, but `register_globals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go and make changes in the `php.ini` for the `register_globals` setting as **OFF**

Also beware that there is a **[security risk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)**(*as it makes server, cookie etc variables as global*) which is involved in using `register_globals`. Better option would be change that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
while (list($k, $v) = each ($_GET)) {
    $$k = $v;
}
```

The "$$" is correct! This is a variable variable.
So all your $_GET-pairs will be accessable without $_GET. You can do this with $_SERVER, too.